# Comment line matching some pattern and n strings after it with Ansible

Tags: regex, replace, ansible, comments

I need to comment line that matching a pattern and n lines after it (if there is no comment symbol at the beginning of the line already). When I need to comment any line containing pattern 'reboot' I do it like this:

```
    - name: Excluding reboot command from script
      replace:
        path: "{{some_path}}/someshellscript.sh"
        regexp: '(^(?!.*#).*reboot.*)'
        replace: '#\1'
```

This task commenting lines with 'reboot' and regex won't match '#reboot'.
But what if I need to comment line with 'reboot' and two lines after it when this lines hasn't commented yet?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can reliably predict what your line returns are going to be, and there isn't going to be a variance in the number of lines you need to comment after the regex match, you could use this:

```
- name: Excluding reboot command from script
  replace:
    path: "{{some_path}}/someshellscript.sh"
    regexp: '(^(?!.*#).*reboot.*\n)(.*\n)(.*)'
    replace: '#\1#\2#\3'
```